# How to load different text into the same view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a list of 20 chapters in my app. When each is clicked they load text related to that chapter into a new view. My question is how can i store this data and load it into the new view?

The data is static so doesn't need to be editable, but I cant seem to get my head around how to load the text in with the format i'd like (for example chapter 1 is roughly twice the size as chapter 2, with different headings etc so I cant just loop through the text to format at the same points in each chapter).

Ive tried loading html files into a `UIWebView` but apple rejected this on the grounds that the app ended up basically being a website. There must be an easy way to store formatted data in files, which can then be loaded into a `UITextView` or something like that, but I cant seem to fathom it out on my own!

Thanks for your help!!

PeterB

Comment: If you have a bunch of textual "chapters" in HTML format and you're simply displaying them and doing nothing else...well, have you considered selling your product as an e-book instead of an app? You'll get compatibility with everything from Android phones to Kindle readers almost for free.

Comment: Its a good idea, but it needs a little bit more functionality than ive mentioned, its just this part of the program im having trouble with! Thanks for the offering though!

Comment: If there's functionality you can't get through an e-book or website, you should point out that functionality specifically to App Review as the reason you need this to be an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out `NSAttributedString`?  This a great way to have some really custom formatted and styled text.  You can then store these in an Array that is kept in `NSUserDefaults` or a singleton.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! To elaborate a little, say my chapters were about the size of the page you linked to in your answer, surely all that text with all the headings and formatting etc wouldn't be stored in separate strings would they?

Comment: They could be stored however you want.  It could be a string for the title and then a string for each body.  It could also be one large string (that is the power of `NSAttributedString`

Comment: So its acceptable coding to have maybe 1000+ NSAtrributedStrings, and only load the ones for that particular page into memory, maybe using loops etc? I dont mean to question you, I just dont want to re-write the entire html files into a different format only for apple to reject it again!

Comment: They shouldn't reject you for coding a certain way.  As long as you are following the Human Interface Guidelines (which doesn't really get into how to code (except that it shouldn't crash, block UI thread, etc) Apple shouldn't have an issue with your app.  BTW, you should have got a review person to deal with when the app was rejected. It is always good to communicate directly with that person.  Actually, I imagine that if you explained what you were doing with the UIWebView's, they might just accept the version you have.

Comment: No, i didnt get assigned anyone, just an option to appeal against the rejection. Which I did and I just got sent back the same generic message as in the original rejection. Its a little frustrating as I would like to ask someone exactly what needs to be done to the app to get it through the review!